# How to read Jenkins Parameters?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to Read Parmeters in jenkins job. I have set String Parameter for Job as follows.

[image: String Parameter]

but when I am tring to read this parameter in windows batch command as

[image: Node Number]

it wont read it's value but simply return variable name only as follows

[image: Output]

I have also installed parameterized trigger plugin.
Is there any additional plugin I need to install?
Kindly suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows, it's `%NODENUMBER%` (or when using delayed expansion: `!NODENUMBER!`)
In *nix, it's `$NODENUMBER` or `${NODENUMBER}` (curly brackets are only required when there is ambiguity with adjacent words, but are a good habit anyways)